# Dynamically inherit class based on parameter to make 2 classes be 1

Tags: python, django

I am facing this issue that I can't seem to solve by myself.
My goal is to create a custom model field based on both `FileField` and `ImageField` from django. I also need to add extra parameters (`bucket_name`, `privacy` (not mandatory because it has a default fallback)) to handle upload

I want to call, in an app's `models.py`, MyCustomFileField instead of either of the two mentioned above, like this:

```
image = MyCustomFileField(
    'Image',
    upload_to='path',
    blank=True,
    null=True,
    max_length=255,
    privacy='public',
    bucket_name='somebucket',
    file_type='file' # or 'image'
)
```

my custom field logic:

```
class MyCustomFileField(models.FileField): <---- This would need to be dynamic based on kwargs['file_type']
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if 'bucket_name' not in kwargs:
        raise ImproperlyConfigured(
            "No parameter `bucket_name` was passed to `%s`" % (self.__class__.__name__)
        )
    if 'privacy' not in kwargs:
        kwargs['storage'] = storage_backends.PublicMediaStorage(bucket_name=kwargs['bucket_name'])
    else:
        if kwargs['privacy'] == 'private':
            kwargs['storage'] = storage_backends.PrivateMediaStorage(bucket_name=kwargs['bucket_name'])
        elif kwargs['privacy'] == 'public':
            kwargs['storage'] = storage_backends.PublicMediaStorage(bucket_name=kwargs['bucket_name'])
        else:
            raise ImproperlyConfigured(
                "Parameter `privacy` only accepts following values: '%s', '%s'" %
                ('private', 'public')
            )

    kwargs.pop('privacy', None)
    kwargs.pop('bucket_name', None)
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

I could have two classes, one for each inheritance (ImageField and FileField) but the logic inside the class (where I manage the bucket and the privacy) is so far the exact same. So i'd have two different classes that do the exact same but just inherit a different class.

Gross right?

What is the best way to do this? Am I even on the right track or should I try another approach to tackle my problem? I'll take any advice about any part of the code. Thank you.

Comment: Use a base class with the common logic, then just create two classes that inherit from that common base class, and choose from those two classes based on what you need

Comment: Changing inheritance based on an argument to the constructor *makes no sense*, the class already exits at that point, it's base-classes are already set

Comment: Doesn't that mean that in my models.py, ill go back to having two ways of calling for a file? CustomeFile & CustomImage ? You're saying I shouldn't try to have 1 that does the two?